# Random polynomial and $x^n - 1$

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $f(x) = x^n - 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Now suppose that $g(x)$ is a randomly chosen polynomial of degree $\leq n - 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$

What is the probability that $\gcd(f, g) = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's generalize:

> How many monic polynomials of degree $D$ divide $x^n-1$ within $\mathbb{F}_q$?

We will reduce this to the problem of counting nonnegative solutions to a linear equation.

First, write $n=q^km$ with $q\nmid m$, so $x^n-1=(x^m-1)^{q^k}$. The irreducible factors of $x^m-1$ correspond to the $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_q(\mu_m)/\mathbb{F}_q)$-orbits (where $\mu_m$ are the roots of $x^m=1$). We don't actually need to calculate these orbits or the corresponding factors - it suffices to determine how many factors there are of each degree.

Every $m$th root is expressible as $g^{uv}$ where $u\in(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $v\mid m$. (This can be proved by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem on $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.) Note $g^{uv}$ is a primitive $(m/v)$th root of unity. The size of this orbit is the smallest $k$ for which $q^k(uv)\equiv uv$ mod $m$, which is equivalent to $(m/v)\mid (q^k-1)$ (note the Frobenius automorphism $\wp(x)=x^q$ generates the Galois group), which is $k=\mathrm{ord}_{m/v}(q)$. Setting $d=m/v$, we can say there are $\varphi_d=\phi(d)/\mathrm{ord}_d(q)$-many irreducible factors of $x^m-1$ of degree $\mathrm{ord}_d(q)$ which are minimal polynomials of $d$th roots.

We may write $g(x)$ as a product of these irreducible factors, each with multiplicity $e\le q^k$.

Therefore, the answer to the general problem equals the number tuples $\big(e_i^{(d)}\big)$ satisfying

$$ \sum_{d\mid m} \mathrm{ord}_d(q)\big(e_1^{(d)}+\cdots+e^{(d)}_{\varphi_d}\big) = D $$

with $0\le e_{i}^{(d)}\le q^k$ for all $d\mid m,1\le i\le \varphi_d$.